# unable handle exception from future failure

Tags: scala, exception, playframework-2.0, future

I want the following code to return a custom message when one of the method, `callfuture1()` or `callfuture2()`, throws an exception. My understanding was if either of the future fails, `f` would be a failed future.

However, when `callfuture1` throws an exception. `f.onFailure` is not executed. Instead I see the call stack stopped at line of code in `callFuture1()` where exception occurred and a standard internalError is returned. Why does that happen?

```
val f = for {
 x <- callfuture1()
 y <- callfuture2()
} yield y

f.onFailure {
 //send an internalserver error with some custom message
}

f.map {
 //send data back
}
```

**====update====**

i see from the responses, that potential issue is that Exception is being thrown outside the Future and hence my code fails to catch that failed future. 
So i changed the code such that Exception only occurs inside the future. I still am not able to explain the behavior i am seeing. (I wonder if it has to anything to do with Play framework.)

```
def controllerfunction(id: String) = Action.async{

  val f = for{
    x <- callfuture1(id)
    y <- callfuture2(x)
  } yield y

  y.onFailure{case t => 
    println("This gets printed");
    Ok("shit happened, but i am still ok")}

  y.map{resp:String => Ok(resp)}

}

def callfuture1(id: String):Future[Obj1] = {
  for {
    val1 <- callfuture1.1(id)
    val2 <- callfuture1.2(val1)
  } yield val2
}

def callfuture1.2:Future[Obj3] = Future{
  thrown new Exception("TEST ME");
}

def callfuture 1.1:Future[Obj4] = {...}
def callfuture2: Future[String] = {....}
```

**Expectation.**
The method callfuture1.2 throws an exception inside the future, so my expectation is onFailure should be executed, (which does get executed), and the response returned should "Shit happened, but i am still ok"

**Actuality**
The play framework returns InternalServerError and i see error stack on my console. I see the printlin("This gets printed") is getting executed.

Cant understand what is happening. Any insights?

**==== update 2 =====**

I verified that the issue only happens when called inside controller of play framework ( i am using play 2.5). As a standalone scala program everthing works as expected. I believe play error handling catches the unhandaled exception and prints the stack trace. I think this should only be happening in development environment.

Comment: Try `val f1 = callfuture1(); val f2 = callfuture2; f = for { x <- f1; y <- f2 } yield y`. Difference is that in your case futures are executing sequentally (y waits for callfuture1 to complete).

Comment: What do you mean by "stack stopped"? What is " standard internal error"? How do you know `onFailure` is not executed? What is the actual error?

Comment: Also. note that `onFailure` can only be used for side effects. It can't change the exception contained in the `Future`. If you want to fiddle with the exception, you need to use `transform` or `recover`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if `callfuture1` throws "outside of a future".
Your for comprehension is desugared into this:

```
val f = callfuture1.flatMap{ x =>
  callfuture2.map{ y =>
    y
  }
}
```

If `callfuture2` throws right away (as opposed to returning a failed future), you will still end up with a failed future because `callfuture2`  is called inside `Future.flatMap`, which catches exceptions and turns them into failed futures (same for `Future.map`).

The situation is different for `callfuture1`: if it  throws right away, there is no enclosing `Future.map` or `Future.flatMap` to turn it into a failed future.

In general you should try to avoid having a method that returns a `Future` and can **also** throw an error.
This means that if `callfuture1` does anything that can throw, it should catch that and turn the exception in a failed future that you then return.

**UPDATE**: Concerning your update about how you expected "Shit happened, but i am still ok" to be returned:

As already hinted by Dima in a comment, `Future.onFailure` can only be used for side effects. Futures are immutable. If you want to recover from a failed exception, there is no way to modify the original (failed) future and all you can actually do is transform it into a new future.
Have a look at [`Future.recover`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]). It does exactly what you need, namely it allows to transform an input future by matching the failed result (if any) and transforming it into a successful future. It is the equivalent of a catch clause, but for futures. Concretely what you really meant to do is something like this:

```
def controllerfunction(id: String) = Action.async{
  val f = for{
    x <- callfuture1(id)
    y <- callfuture2(x)
  } yield y

  f.map{ resp: String => 
    Ok(resp)
  }.recover{
    case t: Throwable => 
      println("This gets printed");
      Ok("shit happened, but i am still ok")
  }
}
```

Comment: i updated the question. i addressed the issue of exception being thrown outside the future, but i am still seeing the behavior i cant explain :(. any insights?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that inside `callfuture1()` you're not wrapping all your process inside the Future constructor like

```scala
def callfuture1(): Future[?] = Future {
  val x = ...
  x
}
```

but your code seems to be

```scala
def callfuture1(): Future[?] = {
  val x = ... // some error happen here
  Future(x)
}
```

so because it's outside the future, your error is throwing directly into your program code

Comment: answers is not a place to ask questions, use comments

Comment: I know but I don't have enough reputation for now